# Lower bounds on eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix based on the diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A symmetric matrix $A$ always has real eigenvalues. If I know the elements on the diagonals, is it possible to have a lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue? How sharp would this bound be?

For now I only found a paper of Hemy WoIkowicz and George P. H. Styan titled as "Bounds for Elgenvalues Using Traces", however, their bounds require the trace of $A^2$ which needs the other entries.

Is there any other bounds or references on this topic?

p.s. I cannot assume that $A$ is positive-definite coz I know that the smallest eigenvalue is $0$ indeed.

Comment: The [Geršgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) might interest you.

Comment: Yes, I already took a look at, but it is generally more rough than the bounds in the paper I mention.

Comment: No, the only thing you can get from the diagonals are upper bounds on (the absolute values of) eigenvalues.

Comment: As I recall one can prove that the estimate from Gerschgorin's theorem is tight, even in the symmetric case. So I don't think you can do any better if all you know is the diagonal entries and the absolute row/column sums.

Answer (score 4):

No, look at the following matrix and its generalizations
$$ \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Its eigenvalues are $\pm a$ while the diagonal is always zero.

Comment: But this matrix is not positive definite. From the question, it seems that OP is asking about positive definite matrices.